# ngx-sharebuttons getting No Provider for Http

Tags: angular, share-button

Using Angular 4, and planning to use ngx-sharebuttons (https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-sharebuttons)

Butt getting this error.

```
ShareButtonComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: No provider for Http!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the http import

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule,ShareButtonsModule.forRoot()],// missing http import module
    providers: [],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
....
```

Demo for The share button [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts) click on contact card

In the official Wiki link for the share button the HttpModule is required Please check this [link](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-sharebuttons/wiki#add-share-buttons)

Comment: reason for dv ?